# QNetworkAccessManger get returns invalid XML as response for few URLs in Qt

Tags: xml, qt, rss

I am using the QNetworkAccessManager to read the news from the a news portal below is an example

```
QNetworkReply *reply;
QNetworkAccessManager *network = new QNetworkAccessManager;
network->setNetworkAccessible(QNetworkAccessManager::Accessible);
reply = network->get(QNetworkRequest(QUrl(“http://news.yahoo.com/rss/sports”)));
```

Another URL to test “http://news.yahoo.com/rss/baseball”

some url will get the proper xml content but few will be not recieve the proper contents.

similar issue i am facing when i am trying to use the qt example for news reader .
QtSDK/demos/4.7/declarative/rssnews

Example for Invalid XML obtained looks something like below : (Proper XML should have title, description tags)

```
<?xml version=“1.0” encoding=“UTF-8” ?><!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC “-//WAPFORUM//DTD XHTML Mobile 1.0//EN” “http://www.wapforum.org/DTD/xhtml-mobile10.dtd”><html lang=“en” xml:lang=“en”><head><title>Sports News Headlines – Yahoo! News</title><meta http-equiv=“Content-Type” content=“text/html; charset=utf-8”/><style type=“text/css”>body{color:#353535;background:#ffffff;font-family:Sans-serif}a{color:#006ec2;text-decoration:none}a.z, a.y, a.x, a.w, a.v, .u a{text-decoration:none}body,div,dl,dt,dd,ul,ol,li,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6{padding:0;margin:0}img{border:0}hr{display:none;visibility:hidden;width:0}#page{background:
………………………..
…………………………………
…………………………………………….
cir0Pb17r9HJLHyL2H6qC_rG”><span>Help</span></a></div><div class=“o p “>ÃƒÂ‚Ã‚Â© 2013 Yahoo! Inc. All rights reserved</div></div></div></div></div>http://us.bc.yahoo.com/b?P=92jfVTc2LjFqpOI6f__DZQGKMTI1LlFSw2X_m5fY&T=1ehh1jvjf/X=1364378469/E=954001251/R=mi/K=5/V=10.1/W=C/Y=YAHOO/F=1168823538/H=YmVzdC13b2VpZD0iMjI5NTQyMCIgY2Fycmllcj0iSU4tVU5LTk9XTiIgY29udGVudD0ibW9iaWxlX25ld3MiIGR2Y19jbHM9IjQiIHBuPSJ5YWhvb19tb2JpbGVfdXNfd2ViIiBycz0icHJpOnlhaG9vX21vYmlsZV91c193ZWI7c2VjOnlhaG9vO2NycjpJTi1VTktOT1dOOyIgc2VydmVJZD0iOTJqZlZUYzJMakZxcE9JNmZfX0RaUUdLTVRJMUxsRlN3MlhfbTVmWSIgc2l0ZUlkPSI0OTAyNTUxIiB0U3RtcD0iMTM2NDM3ODQ2OTk3MTg3MCIg/Q=-1/I=1/S=1/J=36F70D4C&U=12cle5obm/N=TWHUE2KJiVo-/C=-1/D=WFB2/B=-1/V=0 <!— SpaceID:954001251 —></body></html> 
<!— webgw51.mobile.sp1.yahoo.com uncompressed/chunked Wed Mar 27 10:01:09 GMT 2013 —>
<!— fe621.global.media.sg3.yahoo.com uncompressed/chunked Wed Mar 27 10:01:09 UTC 2013 —>
```

Comment: What is your question? If there is something not working add the error message or describe what happens.

Comment: updated my querry with error xml recieved. from the point exampl for invalid xml

Comment: And why do you think that "invalid xml" is Qt fault?

Comment: @KamilKlimek . In the sample qt rss example also i am able to find this problem .any pointer in this direction will be very helpfull.

Comment: Seems more like page you're using is producing invalid xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem occurs because QNetworkAccessManager sets the header `User-Agent` to `Mozilla/5.0` by default (tested with Qt 4.8.4 and Qt 5.1.1). That causes the yahoo server to return an HTML-formatted version meant for display in a browser (firefox and friends, in this case).

To enforce RSS, set the `User-Agent` header to something not recognized as browser:

```
...
QNetworkRequest request(QUrl("http://news.yahoo.com/rss/sports"));
request.setRawHeader("User-Agent", "MyFancyApplication");
QNetworkReply *reply = network->get(request);
...
```